# How to make a Dynamic Calculator to solve a quadratic equation?

Tags: equation-solving, dynamic

Taking my first steps in the world of Mathematica Programming.

The aim of my program was to modify Wolfram's dynamic calculator
(which performs an addition subtraction and a product - in response to the user inputting two values used to perform these operations)
 to now take three input and display on the three outputs:

[1] the quadratic equation to be solved
[2] the roots of this quadratic equation
[3] the discriminant of this equation

The three things (in red text) which you have to input are:

first input box is coefficient a
second input box is coefficient b
third input box is coefficient c

These coefficients represent a,b and c in the quadratic equation
$ax^2 + bx +c$

So the Wolfram Demonstration & My attempt (the code below) look like this:
http://www.controlmanchester.com/2013/08/01/quadratic-equation-images/

The code for the original program is available here:
http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/example/ConstructADynamicCalculator.html

This is the code that I have written (modified really):

```
 DynamicModule[ 
      {a = 0, b = 0, c = 0}, 
      Deploy[ 
       Style[ 
        Panel[ 
         Grid[ 
          Transpose[
        {
        {
        Style["input a ", Red],
        Style["input b", Red],
        Style["input c", Red],
    "here is the equation",
    "here is the value of the discriminant",
    "here are the roots"},

     {InputField[Dynamic[a], Number],
     InputField[Dynamic[b], Number],
     InputField[Dynamic[c], Number],
     InputField[Dynamic[a*x^2 + b*x + c],Enabled -> False],
     InputField[Dynamic[b]^2 - (4*Dynamic[a]*Dynamic[c]) , Enabled -> False],
     InputField[Dynamic[a b], Enabled -> False]}
            }
                ]
    , Alignment -> Right]
    , ImageMargins -> 10]
       , 
    DefaultOptions -> {InputField -> {ContinuousAction -> True, 
    FieldSize -> {{5, 30}, {1, Infinity}}}}]
    ]
    ]
```

I have discovered, via trial and error, 
that within an input field I cannot simply 
try something like
`Solve[x^2 + a x + 1 == 0, x]` or `Roots[    ]`.

I think this is where the heart of my problem lies.

At the moment the variables I put in do propagate down 
and show the coefficients of the quadratic, but I cannot get 
any further with it.

Any help, or guidance to things I should read are most welcome.

Many Thanks,
David

p.s. I have seen from the answer by Mike Honeychurch that I have not described the problem as clearly as possible. I have edited the post :) 
I hope this makes my problem easier to understand

Comment: "First steps in the world of Mathematica Programming" and "DynamicModule..." — yikes! :)

Comment: I think Nasser is right - `Manipulate` is a better place to start than `DynamicModule`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My first thought was this:

```
Manipulate[
 Grid[
  {
   {TraditionalForm[u]},
   {"Equation", Row[{u, " = 0"}]},
   {"Solutions", Solve[u == 0, x]},
   {"Roots", Roots[u == 0, x]},
   {"Discriminant", Discriminant[u, x]}
   }, Alignment -> Left], 
 {{u, x^2 + 2 x + 1}},
 BaseStyle -> FontSize -> 16]
```

[image: equationsolver]

Comment: +1 this is exactly what I was trying to write but in far less code. I have learned something about the complexities of dynamic vs manipulate. Thanks.

Comment: :) Cool, and thanks. Even experienced users mutter under their breath about the complexities of `Dynamic` and `DynamicModule`...

Answer (score 2):

Sorry but it is unclear to me what you want to be able to type in the input fields and what you want to see. If you use `InputField[expr, Hold[Expression]]` you can type `Solve[...]`. Here is an example (which is why I have made this an "answer" --though it is not really an answer 'cause I am unsure what you want -- rather than a comment).

```
DynamicModule[{z = Null},

 Column[{

   InputField[Dynamic[z], Hold[Expression]],
   Dynamic[ReleaseHold[z]]

   }]
 ]
```

[image]

or

```
DynamicModule[{z = Null},

 Column[{

   InputField[Dynamic[z], Hold[Expression]],
   Spacer[{0, 15}],
   Dynamic[
    If[Head[ReleaseHold[z]] === Equal, Solve[ReleaseHold[z], x], 
     Spacer[0]]]

   }]
 ]
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your Answer Mike.
I have modified the question to make it more readable.
I have also linked to a website I administrate where you can see images of both the output of the wolfram example and of the one I have written. @MikeHoneychurch