# Solving the symbolic quadratic equation ax2 + bx + c = 0

Tags: equation-solving

I need to ask *Mathematica* to  solve the symbolic quadratic equation `ax2 + bx + c = 0`.
Does it give you the right answer?

Comment: Could you provide the equation in proper *Mathematica* code? Do you mean `a x^2 +b x+c==0`?

Comment: the command to solve polynomial is called `Solve`. Try it and if you still can't do it, post what you tried.

Comment: Mathematica can't answer that question because (I'm batman) it assumes that a,b and c are variables. The answer you are looking for (quadratic formula will not be given) Not directly though you can try this link <Link> in a minute</link>

Comment: The link is [here]


[here]http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/29667/how-to-make-a-dynamic-calculator-to-solve-a-quadratic-equation

Answer (score 6):

try with: `Solve[a*x^2 + b*x + c == 0, x]`

Comment: @laura, refer to comment above as you will not be able to get quadratic formula direclty from mathematica.

Answer (score 6):

In Mathematica 10:

```
==Hello I would like to solve the quadratic equation please
```

[image]

Comment: Being polite to the free-form input parser is very important!